# My workplace's proxy is preventing me from using Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, proxy

I work in the public sector so my workplace controls internet access pretty strictly. I've tried configuring the settings.xml file that M2Eclipse reads to no avail. It may be simple user error in my case, but I'd like to explore other options anyways just in case that it isn't.

I was looking at installing a local Nexus repository as I can get around the proxy for some programs (just not Maven in this case), but as of right now I don't even have admin privileges yet to try that solution out.

I suppose that I could also initialise the project on my own VPS, push the project to a git repository and then pull in the project on my work machine as well.

Should I just give up and add the required JARs to the project build path manually?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Cough cough* not that my IT guy would appreciate me telling you this, but with the right configuration you can generally fool most proxies into letting you through.

[First you have to configure your maven http proxy in settings.xml](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html)

```
<settings>
  .
  .
  <proxies>
   <proxy>
      <id>example-proxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy.example.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>somepassword</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.example.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
  .
  .
</settings>
```

[Then you have to modify your User-Agent](https://brettporter.wordpress.com/2009/06/16/configuring-maven-http-connections/):

```
<server>
  <id>archiva.localhost</id>
  <configuration>
    <httpHeaders>
      <property>
        <name>User-Agent</name>
        <value>Internal-Build-System/1.0</value>
      </property>
    </httpHeaders>
  </configuration>
</server>
```

So for example, if your organization only allows a certain version of internet explorer through the proxy, this is how you lie and claim that maven is that version of internet explorer so it won't bother you.

If this doesn't work because they fundamentally block the sites you need to pull JARs from, then you can get even tricker; yes it involves a VPS.   One option would be to use git as you say.

Another option (IT guys hate this, do so at your own risk, as whatever your local policy is this probably violates it) is to set up your VPS as an HTTP proxy.  You might set up something like Squid on your VPS, and then set up an [SSH tunnel](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html) from your work machine to the VPS which connects to your HTTP proxy.  So the way this would work is that your work machine would use an HTTP proxy that was a local port (say localhost:8080).  That local port would connect to an SSH tunnel across some network-acceptable port (e.g. 80) to your VPS.  Once the traffic gets there, your VPS is your HTTP proxy and your organization's proxy has been bypassed.

That would fail if your IT department has deep packet inspection set up, or bans the IP range of your VPS, or some other combination.  But the bottom line is that if they let you pass network packets at all, they can do all sorts of things to make your life difficult, but if you are clever they probably can't stop you from setting up your own proxy and bypassing most/all of their infrastructure.

Comment: My... My god. It's brilliant.

Comment: With great power comes great responsibility, young Padwan.

Answer (score 0):

create settings.xml file under `<your_home_folder>/.m2` folder. (settings.xml file never get create automatically at this location, So you can copy this file from `<maven_install_dir>/conf/` folder  to `<your_home_folder>/.m2` and override)

Now edit this file at `<your_home_folder>/.m2/settings.xml` and un-comment the following porting in `settings.xml` file and configure with your proxy settings.

```
<proxies>
<proxy>
  <id>optional</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <username>proxyuser</username>
  <password>proxypass</password>
  <host>proxy.host.net</host>
  <port>80</port>
  <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
```

Now re-run your maven job.